# Why can a Random Forest generate extreme values?

Tags: regression, cart

I'm training a Random Forest Regressor, and I'm using a target variable thats values are between negative and positive 40. The regressor performs relatively well, however, I've noticed sometimes it generates extreme values. For example, it can generate values that cause some errors of around 60 (so, for example, for a value that should be 0, it generates 60). Why could this happen in theory and how to prevent it?

Comment: If your outputs are constrained, you should think about transforming them into an unconstrained space, training your model in that space, and then back transforming the model predictions.  This will guarentee your model only predicts things between the bounds.

Comment: I'm surprised. CARTs, on which random forest is built, cut the range of y up into pieces (leaves) according to the predictors. If the combination of x would, in a linear regression, lead to values larger than those observed, in random forest (and CART) it would only yield the value of the largest leaf (e.g the mean of y of all cases in that leaf). Thus, it is impossible to predict values larger (or smaller) than those observed. Please provide a minimal working example of such an impossibility.

Comment: I think your *extreme* error was something like predicting 30 for a target -30, instead of predicting 60 for a target for $0$.

Comment: The answer seems kind of trivial, but this happens because the ensemble is predicting values that are similar to the training data (i.e. by averaging outcomes in terminal leafs). If it's producing a prediction with a large residual somewhere, it's because that value is very large relative to the values that belong to the most-similar training data, i.e. the training data belonging to the terminal leafs of the large residual prediction. So it seems like either (1) the model is misfit; or (2) this observation is an outlier.